# What should I use Array.from or spread operator [...] in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been playing with TypeScript and I ran into a problem I wrote a shorthand for `querySelectorAll()`

```
export function selectAll(DOMElement: string, parent = document): Array<HTMLElement> | null {
    return [...parent.querySelectorAll(DOMElement)];
}
```

The above code giving me `Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement[]'`.

Then I changed my code a little bit

```
export function selectAll(DOMElement: string, parent = document): Array<HTMLElement> | null {
    return Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll(DOMElement));
}
```

Now I am not getting any error. So, my questions are -

- Why `Array<HTMLElement>` didn't work but `Array<Element>` worked.
- What should I use `[...]` spread operator or `Array.from()`.

**In Addition**

Like [bogdanoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14112947/bogdanoff) mentioned in comment

*"from docs `querySelectorAll` returns a non-live NodeList containing `Element` so `Array<Element>` is right type."*

Then why `querySelector` is okay with returning `HTMLElement` instead of just `Element`

```
export function selectAll(DOMElement: string, parent = document): HTMLElement | null {
    return parent.querySelector(DOMElement);
}
```

Comment: from docs _querySelectorAll returns a non-live `NodeList` containing `Element`_ so `Array<Element>` is right type.

Comment: I'd think `{...}` refers to *object spread* and not *array spread* which would maybe be better rendered as `[...]`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the suggestion I changed the title

Answer (score 2):

### what happens behind the hoods

In order to understand what is going on, we need to look at how typescript defines the signature for `Array.from` and `querySelectorAll`. Excerpts:

```
from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): T[];
querySelectorAll<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): NodeListOf<E>;
```

For `Array.from`, it means that, given a type T, it will return an array of elements with type T. If no T is given, it could be anything.

Specifying a type for the return value of the function is actually saying: *"please take T = HTMLElement"*. In turn, that implies the argument arrayLike will have type `ArrayLike<HTMLElement>`.
`NodeListOf<E>` will match this by taking E = HTMLElement, which does extend Element, so it is valid, and typescript is happy.

### why does typescript behave so?

Because **you are *deliberately* giving the HTMLElement type** for the return value, typescript trusts you and is capable to give specific types to E and T.

### to go beyond

Interestingly, the following code would raise a typescript error:

```js
function selectAll(DOMElement: string, parent = document): Array<HTMLElement>  {
  const all = parent.querySelectorAll(DOMElement);
  return Array.from(all);
}
```

This is because on the line defining `all`, there is no information whatsoever about what type E could be, so it defaults to being `Element`. When parsing the `return` line, TS will (rightly) complain that `Element` cannot map to `HTMLElement`.

### Conclusion

To your questions:

- *use spread operator or Array.from* => in your case, spread operator is not an option since it raises an error, which `Array.from` does not
- *why querySelector is okay with returning HTMLElement instead of just Element?* => hopefully, the above has clarified why

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the snippet you've provided and I think `Array.from` casts Element[] into HTMLElement[]

```
function selectAll(DOMElement: string, parent = document): Array<HTMLElement> | null {
    const m : Array<HTMLElement> | null=  Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll(DOMElement));
    return m
}


function selectAll2(DOMElement: string, parent = document): Array<HTMLElement> | null {
    const m =  Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll(DOMElement));
    return m
}
```

If you check selectAll2 will throw an error.

And this won't work in

```
const arr = ["a","b"];

const setup1 = () : number[] => {
    return [...arr]
}

const setup1 = () : number[] => {
    return Array.from(arr)
}
```

cause HTMLElement is a child class of Element[] itself.